# Service not starting - after performing change in activity/ fragment ?! :/ Android 4.3 / Xperia z1

Tags: android, service, camera, fragment

really strange: the following behavior:

I have a camera application and a service which processes the image data.
If activity /fragment starts, portrait mode is active, and everything works as expected.

if now the user changes camera (button in UI), exactly the same code is executed, but service is not starting.

code below:

```
Intent saveImageIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SaveImageService.class);
getActivity().startService(saveImageIntent);
```

service in manifest:

```
<service android:name="packageName.SaveImageService" />
```

service code:

```
public class SaveImageService
    extends
    IntentService {

      public SaveImageService() {
           super("SaveImageService");
      }

      @Override
      public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
           Log.i(Constants.DEBUG, "SaveImageService started");
           //processing image data here if valid
      } 
}
```

i nearly tried everything, before it was an asynctasc and everything worked fine, but i decided to create a service to be more "clean" in code.

and now this really strange problem.
as i mentioned before:

at first everything works perfect, after changing camera (activity, fragment not restarted) nothing done more or less. debugged with break-points, code is executed, image is taken, but startService... code is executed,
but finally:service onHandleIntent not triggered...

btw. on emulator this seems to be working fine all the time.

**Problem occurring on Android 4.3 - XPeria Z1**
**Problem occurring on Android 4.4.2 - Samsung S4**

---

**Some new information:**

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SaveImageService.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putByteArray(Constants.EXTRA_IMAGE_DATA, imgData);
bundle.putInt(Constants.EXTRA_IMAGE_ROTATION_DEGREES, catchedDeviceOrientation);
bundle.putBoolean(Constants.STORE_IMAGE_USING_FFV, frontFacingCamera);
serviceIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IMAGE_BUNDLE, bundle);

getActivity().getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
```

**Service Intent without bundle is always starting… what could be the reason?**

Comment: Very strange indeed, your code seems to be fine. Can you try using Service instead of intent service.

Comment: thanks @ZealDeveloper, already tried it that way too, no change at all :( the only thing happening between case(1) and case(2) is setting camera member to null, switching camera, and restarting preview ;) nothing else changes, got really no idea.
in the meantime just replaced complete service by asynctask (more or less just renamed onHandleIntent to doInBackground) and everything works as expected. :(

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: None.
Possible reason.

Data in Intent has some size limits,
the problem seems to be, that the picture acquired by the "normal" Back-Camera is much bigger than the FFC (so far so clear), and this **data is just too big to pass it through intent.**

Basically it makes no sense, that it just doesn't execute onHandleIntent(…) ...
but this really looks like if it's the reason.

**Without** passing the **image data** to the intent as byte[], the service will **always be executed**.
**correctly.**
**all the time.**

hope this information helps someone.
**good luck**, 
Mike